# Is there an equivalent of x++ that can be used in an expression for incrementing by values greater than 1?

Tags: java, increment, post-increment

Apologies for the slightly confusing title.

It is well known that

```
    int x = 4;
    System.out.println(x++); // prints 4
    x = 4;
    System.out.println(++x); //prints 5
```

By experimentation, I found that

```
    int x = 4;
    System.out.println(x+=4); //prints 8
```

Is there an analog of the above that will increment x but print 4 instead?

Comment: Question is a bit unclear. `x+=4` increments x by 4...

Answer (score 1):

Like other assignment operators, shorthand assignment returns the final value.
This allows you to write

```
x = y = z += 4;
```

There is no post-shorthand operator that returns the original value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
int x = 4;
System.out.println((x+=4)-4); //prints 4
```

or

```
int x = 4;
System.out.println((x+=4)-x); //prints 4
```

however, there's no shortcut operands for that scenario you are referring to. :)

Comment: This doesn't make sense. He's asking whether or not there exists an operator similar to ++ which might do the same thing with an arbitrary increment.

Answer (score 0):

++x is pre increment and x++ is post increment

```
//pre increment
int x = 3;
System.out.println(++x); //prints 4
System.out.println(x); //prints 4

//post increment
int y = 7;
System.out.println(y++); //prints 7
System.out.println(y); // this will print 8 now because of the postincrement
```

so I think the answer to your question would be the postincrementing of the variable.